# SmartTarget Promotion issue

Tags: 2013, smarttarget, fredhopper

I have installed SmartTarget 2014 SP1 on Trdion 2013 SP1 and able to create/save prmotion from targeting in CM. These promtions are also getting reflected in Business Manager. Issue is the promotions are not getting returned in my webpage and shows the fallback content always. I have added the Add to Smarttarget tbb in my DCT. Below is the page sourse and the log. Please advise.

**SmartTarget log from my website –**

```
2015-02-26 16:17:20,301 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Retrieving fredhopper query result from query thread, timeout: 500 ms.
2015-02-26 16:17:20,301 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Started fredhopper query call
2015-02-26 16:17:20,301 DEBUG Query - initializing web service client for: http://crassstfhdev02:9180/fredhopper-ws/services/FASWebService?wsdl
2015-02-26 16:17:20,301 DEBUG Query - Constructing Fredhopper query
2015-02-26 16:17:20,301 INFO  Query - Executing query: fh_location=//catalog01/en_US/categories<{catalog01_tcm_0_82_1}&fh_user_date=20150226&st_region=RightRail&st_active_period=20150226&st_publication=tcm%3A0-82-1
2015-02-26 16:17:20,348 DEBUG Section - Creating section with title: categories, name: categories, section type: Cat, number of links: 2
2015-02-26 16:17:20,348 DEBUG Section - Creating section with title: categories, name: categories, section type: Cat, number of links: 1
2015-02-26 16:17:20,379 DEBUG ResultSet - Changing the tcmuri's of 'tcm_82-48420-16_tcm_82-48131-32' to be in context of Publication 'tcm:0-82-1'.
2015-02-26 16:17:20,379 DEBUG ResultSet - Resulting item URI: tcm_82-48420-16_tcm_82-48131-32
2015-02-26 16:17:20,379 DEBUG Query - Query returned 1 item(s)
2015-02-26 16:17:20,379 DEBUG Query - Query returned 0 promotion(s):
2015-02-26 16:17:20,379 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Query result retrieved from fredhopper in: 78 ms.
2015-02-26 16:17:20,379 DEBUG ResultSet - ItemsTotalCount = 1.
2015-02-26 16:28:11,891 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Retrieving fredhopper query result from query thread, timeout: 500 ms.
2015-02-26 16:28:11,891 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Started fredhopper query call
2015-02-26 16:28:11,891 DEBUG Query - initializing web service client for: http://queryserver:9180/fredhopper-ws/services/FASWebService?wsdl
2015-02-26 16:28:11,891 DEBUG Query - Constructing Fredhopper query
2015-02-26 16:28:11,891 INFO  Query - Executing query: fh_location=//catalog01/en_US/categories<{catalog01_tcm_0_82_1}&fh_user_date=20150226&st_region=RightRail&st_active_period=20150226&st_publication=tcm%3A0-82-1
2015-02-26 16:28:11,938 DEBUG Section - Creating section with title: categories, name: categories, section type: Cat, number of links: 2
2015-02-26 16:28:11,938 DEBUG Section - Creating section with title: categories, name: categories, section type: Cat, number of links: 1
2015-02-26 16:28:11,969 DEBUG ResultSet - Changing the tcmuri's of 'tcm_82-48420-16_tcm_82-48131-32' to be in context of Publication 'tcm:0-82-1'.
2015-02-26 16:28:11,969 DEBUG ResultSet - Resulting item URI: tcm_82-48420-16_tcm_82-48131-32
2015-02-26 16:28:11,969 DEBUG Query - Query returned 1 item(s)
2015-02-26 16:28:11,969 DEBUG Query - Query returned 0 promotion(s):
2015-02-26 16:28:11,969 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Query result retrieved from fredhopper in: 78 ms.
2015-02-26 16:28:11,969 DEBUG ResultSet - ItemsTotalCount = 1.
2015-02-26 16:32:35,117 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Retrieving fredhopper query result from query thread, timeout: 500 ms.
2015-02-26 16:32:35,117 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Started fredhopper query call
2015-02-26 16:32:35,133 DEBUG Query - initializing web service client for: http://queryserver:9180/fredhopper-ws/services/FASWebService?wsdl
2015-02-26 16:32:35,133 DEBUG Query - Constructing Fredhopper query
2015-02-26 16:32:35,133 INFO  Query - Executing query: fh_location=//catalog01/en_US/categories<{catalog01_tcm_0_82_1}&fh_user_date=20150226&st_region=RightRail&st_active_period=20150226&st_publication=tcm%3A0-82-1
2015-02-26 16:32:35,164 DEBUG Section - Creating section with title: categories, name: categories, section type: Cat, number of links: 2
2015-02-26 16:32:35,164 DEBUG Section - Creating section with title: categories, name: categories, section type: Cat, number of links: 1
2015-02-26 16:32:35,195 DEBUG ResultSet - Changing the tcmuri's of 'tcm_82-48420-16_tcm_82-48131-32' to be in context of Publication 'tcm:0-82-1'.
2015-02-26 16:32:35,195 DEBUG ResultSet - Resulting item URI: tcm_82-48420-16_tcm_82-48131-32
2015-02-26 16:32:35,195 DEBUG Query - Query returned 1 item(s)
2015-02-26 16:32:35,195 DEBUG Query - Query returned 0 promotion(s):
2015-02-26 16:32:35,195 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Query result retrieved from fredhopper in: 78 ms.
2015-02-26 16:32:35,195 DEBUG ResultSet - ItemsTotalCount = 1.
```

**Page source –**

```
<div id="results-content">
                                <smarttarget:Query AllowDuplicates="false" Publication="tcm:0-82-1" runat="server"> 
                                <smarttarget:Promotions MaxItems="10" Region="RightRail" runat="server"> 
                                                 <ItemTemplate> 
                                                                  <smarttarget:PromotionalItems runat="server"> 
                                                                                                <ItemTemplate> 
                                                                                                                <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:82-48421-64" ComponentURI="<%# Eval(&quot;ComponentUri&quot;) %>" TemplateURI="<%# Eval(&quot;TemplateUri&quot;) %>"/> 
                                                                                                </ItemTemplate> 
                                                                  </smarttarget:PromotionalItems> 
                                                 </ItemTemplate> 
                                                 <FallbackContent>                                                         <h1 style="color: #C60B20; line-height: 1.5;">
                                                                <p>not available.</p>

                                                                </h1>
                                                 </FallbackContent> 
                                </smarttarget:Promotions> 
                </smarttarget:Query>        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When you say they show up in the Business Manager, are you checking the one on port 9180? That's the instance it is querying. Also, are the item(s) selected in the Promotion visible in there too?

Comment: Yes, I can query at 9180 showing the tcm id's of the comp/CT.

Comment: The query is returning 1 item, but 0 promotion. What are the triggers on your promotion? Is it set to "Entire Catalog" meaning no triggers? Is the promotion set to the correct publication 82? Maybe add a screenshot of your promotion definition if possible.

Comment: Now the promotions are intermittently coming. It's not real time, say I made a change in the component, published it and the change I can see is only after few mins or even an hour.

Comment: The Component Presentation content aka the html actually comes from the Tridion Broker db so you may have a Broker caching configuration issue whereby cache is not invalidated correctly. This should not be related to SmartTarget itself. Try to embed your CP directly onto a page without the SmartTarget region code and see if making a change and publishing the component also shows this same latency of update to validate that it is a caching issue. But at least your initial issue is resolved cause you see the promo content onto your page now, correct?

Comment: Its partly fixed.. even sometimes when I change the trigger and expect to see promotion based on that, it gives the fallback content instead of promotion. I'll do the page test and update you

Comment: Once I update the promo and restart the qserver on 9180, majority of times(but not always) the updated promo comes, if I don’t restart then the old contents are shown for long time or forever(may be depending on the caching). Hence the issue is with the qserver and it’s caching.

Is there anyway to invalidate the cache for qserver as I think it retains the promotion in its memory instead of querying the index server every time when the page is hit.

Comment: There is no caching on the qserver -- your changes take effect immediately. What you might be seeing are changes being made on your one instance (port 8180) being synced to the 'live' instance (port 9180) through the syncserver and syncclients. That does indeed have a bit of a delay -- though I've never heard of it being longer than 5 minutes max.

Comment: Hi Pete - you are right, 8180 is working fine but I want to have a separate instance for QS. Where can I check the syncserver and syncclients settings between 810 and 9180?